# Why isn't my custom CSS transition working when updating the state of a parent React component?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, css-transitions, react-functional-component

I'm using functional components with hooks (state hooks mostly) and when I update the "local" state (state within the same component) my custom css transitions works fine. However, when I move this state to the parent component and update it from the child component the css transistion will not work. Instead the changes will render immediately. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried to search for a while but without success. I am making a navbar with a burger menu that will slide in a navigation list from the right when klicked.

**This below will not work**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import "./navbar.css";

const Navbar = (props) => {
  const [scrollState, setScrollState] = useState("top");

  const [burgerOpen, setBurgerOpen] = useState(false); //updating this state transistions does not work!

  const Burger = () => {
    //const [open, setOpen] = useState(false); //updating this state transistions work!

    const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
        setBurgerOpen(!burgerOpen);
      }
    };

    return (
      <>
        <div className={"btn-container"} onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}>
          <div
            className={burgerOpen ? "navbar-btn open" : "navbar-btn"}
            open={burgerOpen}
            onClick={() => setBurgerOpen(!burgerOpen)}
          >
            <div className="navbar-burger" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <Menu open={burgerOpen} key="menu" />
      </>
    );
  };

  const Menu = ({ open }) => {
    return (
      <ul className={open ? "open" : ""}>
        <li>
          <a to="/projects">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a to="/design">Design</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a to="/contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  };

  return (
    <nav
      className={`navbar ${scrollState === "top" ? "dark-nav" : "light-nav"}`}
    >
      <Burger />
    </nav>
  );
};

Navbar.propTypes = {};

export default Navbar;
```

**This however works** but I need to move the state to the parent because of rerenders that I might add (e.g. I want to keep the menu open...)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import "./navbar.css";

const Navbar = (props) => {
  const [scrollState, setScrollState] = useState("top");

  //const [burgerOpen, setBurgerOpen] = useState(false); //updating this state transistions does not work!

  const Burger = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false); //updating this state transistions work!

    const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
        open(!open);
      }
    };

    return (
      <>
        <div className={"btn-container"} onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}>
          <div
            className={open ? "navbar-btn open" : "navbar-btn"}
            open={open}
            onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
          >
            <div className="navbar-burger" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <Menu open={open} key="menu" />
      </>
    );
  };

  const Menu = ({ open }) => {
    return (
      <ul className={open ? "open" : ""}>
        <li>
          <a to="/projects">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a to="/design">Design</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a to="/contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  };

  return (
    <nav
      className={`navbar ${scrollState === "top" ? "dark-nav" : "light-nav"}`}
    >
      <Burger />
    </nav>
  );
};

Navbar.propTypes = {};

export default Navbar;
```

And the CSS:

```
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0.7rem 2rem;
  height: 170px;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.815) 50%,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 50%
    )
    right;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-position: top;
}

.light-nav {
  /*background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);*/
  background-position: bottom;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.navbar li {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.navbar a {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, royalblue, royalblue 50%, #f4f4f4 50%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100%;
  transition: background-position 0.5s ease;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-position: 0 100%;
}

.navbar-logo {
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.navbar-logo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.navbar-btn {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.btn-container:focus > .navbar-btn {
  border: #f4f4f4 1px solid;
}

.btn-container:focus,
.navbar-btn:focus {
  border: none;
}

.navbar-burger {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-burger::before,
.navbar-burger::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-burger::before {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.navbar-burger::after {
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

.navbar-btn.open .navbar-burger {
  transform: translateX(-50px);
  background: transparent;
}

.navbar-btn.open .navbar-burger::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(35px, -35px);
}

.navbar-btn.open .navbar-burger::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(35px, 35px);
}

.navbar-btn:hover .navbar-burger,
.navbar-btn:hover .navbar-burger::before,
.navbar-btn:hover .navbar-burger::after {
  background: royalblue;
}

.navbar-btn.open:hover .navbar-burger {
  background: transparent;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    height: 110px;
  }

  .navbar-logo {
    width: 140px;
  }

  .navbar ul {
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    position: fixed;
    top: 110px;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 200px;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.815);
  }

  .navbar ul li {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }

  .navbar ul.open li {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  .navbar ul li:nth-child(1) {
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
  }
  .navbar ul li:nth-child(2) {
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
  }
  .navbar ul li:nth-child(3) {
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
  }

  .navbar ul.open {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  .navbar-btn {
    visibility: visible;
    display: flex;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

Here is a sandbox of the working example but I need to move out the state of the Burger (**resize for burger menu**):
[Working example (resize!)](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-bash-bhtmd?file=/src/Navbar.js:0-1381)

Comment: You should definitely separate that into small components. Can you console.log(burguerOpen) inside your Burger component?

Comment: @Filipe Nothing strange there I think. It toggles between false and true. I think I must use CSSTransition or something else. I'm trying but without any progress yet...

Comment: @Antonio Hello, were you able to find a solution to this?